# What's the equivalent DynamoDB solution for this MySQL Query?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm familiar with MySQL and am starting to use Amazon DynamoDB for a new project.

Assume I have a MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  scheduledDelivery DATETIME NOT NULL,
  -- ...other columns...
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  INDEX schedIndex (scheduledDelivery)
);
```

Note the secondary Index `schedIndex` which is supposed to speed-up the following query (which is executed periodically):

```
SELECT *
  FROM foo
  WHERE scheduledDelivery <= NOW()
  ORDER BY scheduledDelivery ASC
  LIMIT 100;
```

That is: Take the 100 oldest items that are due to be delivered.

With DynamoDB I can use the `id` column as primary partition key.

However, I don't understand how I can avoid full-table scans in DynamoDB. When adding a secondary index I must always specify a "*partition key*". However, (in MySQL words) I see these problems:

- the `scheduledDelivery` column **is *not* unique**, so it can't be used as a partition key itself AFAIK
- adding `id` as unique partition key and using `scheduledDelivery` as "sort key" sounds like a `(id, scheduledDelivery)` secondary index to me, which makes that index pratically useless

I understand that MySQL and DynamoDB require different approaches, so what would be a appropriate solution in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to avoid a full table scan with this kind of query.

**However**, you may be able to disguise it as a `Query` operation, which would allow you to sort the results (not possible with a `Scan`).

You must first create a [GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html). Let's name it `scheduled_delivery-index`.

We will specify our index's partition key to be an attribute named `fixed_val`, and our sort key to be `scheduled_delivery`.

`fixed_val` will contain any value you want, but it must always be that value, and you must know it from the client side. For the sake of this example, let's say that `fixed_val` will always be `1`.

GSI keys do not have to be unique, so don't worry if there are two duplicated `scheduled_delivery` values.

You would query the table like this:

```
var now = Date.now();

//...

{
   TableName: "foo",
   IndexName: "scheduled_delivery-index",
   ExpressionAttributeNames: {
       "#f": "fixed_value",
       "#d": "scheduled_delivery"
   },
   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
       ":f": 1,
       ":d": now
   },
   KeyConditionExpression: "#f = :f and #d <= :d",
   ScanIndexForward: true
}
```

Comment: That fixed partition key is a great idea (effectively avoiding partitioning). I'm wondering: do people solve problems like the one described here in a completely different way when using DynamoDB/NoSQL? Perhaps using a different table design or even additional tables?